# BIRT report - saving report parameters: user perferences

Tags: parameters, report, birt

We have a report which is available to many users.

We would like to save for each one his preferences ie report parameters in order to make it easier for them by having these parameters already filled every time  they run the report while leaving the possibility to modify these parameters if they wish.

The report parameters are:

- A list which allow multiple values selection
- An input text
- Two date fields

As a solution, we may save the parameters values in a database. So each time the user runs the report, we get the parameters from the database and we set them as default values.

So how we can do that (in more details)? if there is a better solution feel free to suggest it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is the right approach, there are a couple of options to achieve that. How BIRT reports are currently displayed? Through Eclipse Webviewer on Tomcat, a custom java web app, ...?

Comment: Through a custom java webapp.

Comment: I need a practical example about how we can do that.
So thanks if someone could providing this example.

Answer (score 0):

If they are running their reports from a URL or with a web page that generates the URL for them, you can just have them save bookmarks of the URLs they want. If you are using a user management system you could set the BIRT reports to include parameters depending on who is running the report. If you are using the JavaScript API you could capture the parameters and save them as cookies or in the browser's web storage.